# Will messages from chat show up in my inbox by default?

Tags: support, chat

I've been following [a discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21364/discussion-between-anderson-green-and-ohgodwhy), and I've noticed that the replies to my messages haven't been showing up in my inbox. One of the replies that I got (which was 12 hours ago) didn't show up in my inbox for some reason. Is there any way to change the chat settings so that all replies will appear in my StackExchange inbox?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I think someone is telling me that I shouldn't even ask questions like this one. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're actually there in the room and dismissing the replies as you continue chatting, then they won't show up in your inbox. Chat messages are only pushed to your inbox if the reply has been waiting for you to view for some time (I don't know the exact amount) or you're completely absent from the room. If you've already viewed and dismissed it, there's no reason to notify you of the reply and there's no way to change this functionality.

Comment: Surprisingly, I got a reply to one of my messages 12 hours ago and it didn't show up in my inbox.

Comment: Are you sure it was formatted correctly? Sometimes people who type out the name instead of using tab will hit a wrong character or something which causes them not to reply properly. A link to the specific message in question could be useful. I noticed some of his replies don't actually include an `@` notify at the front, which would cause you not to be notified of the message.